# Yii include PHP Excel

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

Im trying include PHPExcel lib to Yii, put `PHPExcel.php` in root of extensions, near `PHPExcel` folder and added that code into `config/main.php`

```
 // application components
'components'=>array(
  'excel'=>array(
  'class'=>'application.extensions.PHPExcel',
),
```

modify `/protected/extensions/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php`

```
public static function Register() {
  $functions = spl_autoload_functions();
  foreach($functions as $function)
    spl_autoload_unregister($function);
  $functions=array_merge(array(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load')), $functions);
  foreach($functions as $function)
    $x = spl_autoload_register($function);
  return $x;
}//     function Register()
```

Then, trying create PHPExcel object `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();`
but have an error: `include(PHPExcel.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory` in `Z:\home\yii.local\www\framework\YiiBase.php(418)`

Answer (score 4):

try these, it work for me.

- Copy files. Copy all files of PHPExcel in ROOT\protected\vendors\PHPExcel. This folder PHPExcel is the folder Classes renamed. Like these:

```
ROOT\protected\vendors\PHPExcel\
                                PHPExcel.php
                                PHPExcel\...
                                         all files php
```

- Load the clases PHPExcel. Modify the file ROOT\index.php. You will change how run the yii app.

```
    $app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);
    // adding PHPExcel autoloader
    Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
    require_once "PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
    require_once "PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php";
    Yii::registerAutoloader(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader','Load'), true);
    $app->run();
```

- Test your PHPExcel. Create a action in any controller

```
    public function actionExcel(){
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        ob_end_clean();
        ob_start();

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your other question, I guess you have found the answer. Alas ... you have to use the import in the config, not components. Something like this:

```
// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.vendors.phpexcel.classes.*',
),
```

You should also put phpexcel in a folder called vendors, not extensions. It is third party software and does not extend Yii.

There is also a guide here that works with disabling Yii autoload, instead of disabling PHPExcel autoload.
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/101/how-to-use-phpexcel-external-library-with-yii/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));             
        Yii::import('ext.phpexcel.Classes.PHPExcel', true);
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```